# How to correctly identify an actor/actresses is in something that is not listed on their IMDB profile?

Tags: casting

While looking for various actors and actresses I keep coming across material they have done that isn't on their IMDB profile.

An example is [Allison Scagliotti](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1270095/) is in a web short yet there is no mention of it on her page, the web short did give her credit but this isn't always the case. I've noticed that music videos and web videos don't normally show up on IMDB as well as sometimes older roles that the actor/actress doesn't acknowledge.

Since IMDB is generally the go to for if an actor/actresses was in something. If it's not listed on IMDB or their wiki page (and in some cases I've come across not the actor/actresses own personal page) then how can I make sure if the actor/actress is the one I believe they are?

Comment: meta discussion:http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/343/does-the-question-need-to-edited-or-did-i-miss-a-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMDb credits are generated by the filmmakers themselves (for smaller, independent productions) or representatives for the filmmakers/producers.

On occasion crew and cast members get left off the submission form. I speak from experience as I appear as three different entities on IMDb because the filmmakers I worked for neglected to see if I was already represented and created a new page for me each time.

This is certainly the case with other actors/crew members, and could go some way to explaining the discrepancies you have discovered.

Bottom line is IMDb is not infallible, and it would indeed require some serious cross-checking with other sites in order to confirm the actor you are researching is the right one.